# get the multi values in prompt and store in an array

Tags: bash, loops

I want to get multiple values from user in my bash script.

for example, I need to have a loop to get `$x` values in prompt like this:

```
Enter parameter 1 : 10
Enter parameter 2 : 12
Enter parameter 3 : 24
```

I wrote this code:

```
x=3
for (( i=1; i<=$x; i++ ))
do
    read -p "Enter parameter ${i} : "  params
done

for i in ${params[@]}
do
   echo $i
done
```

this code shows the prompt for 3 times and gets 3 different value but when I trying to show the values in the `for i in ${params[@]}` I will get just latest value.

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the entry in the array that `read` should save to:

```
params=()
for (( i=1; i<=$x; i++ ))
do
    read -p "Enter parameter ${i} : "  'params[i]'
done
```

For example:

```
bash-5.0$ foo=()
bash-5.0$ read foo[1]
ls
bash-5.0$ read foo[2]
ls
bash-5.0$ read foo[3]
bar
bash-5.0$ echo "${foo[@]}"
ls ls bar
bash-5.0$ echo "${!foo[@]}"
1 2 3
```

Comment: It is suggested that the op  may declare an indexed array using `declare -a params`

Comment: `touch paramsi` and you will have a problem :) I suggest quoting `'params[i]'`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to simply append a temp variable to the output array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

x=3 params=()
for (( i = 1; i <= x; ++i )); do
   IFS= read -rp "Enter parameter #$i: " tmp || continue
   params+=("$tmp")
done

printf '%s\n' "${params[@]}"
```